# present perfect or past perfect in this sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Consider this sentence:

> Yesterday I said to my friend "Excuse me to being late". When I said the sentence I realized that I **have said / had said** a wrong sentence to him!

However, the sentence occurs in the past, but I think that since he is **reporting** his feeling or though just after the saying maybe "have told" is possible.

Comment: We don't "*tell* a sentence". We *say* it. You **realized** that you **had said** something incorrectly.  You **realize** (pres) that you **have said** (pres perf) something incorrectly.

Comment: @tromano you say I could say *When I said the sentence I realize that I have  said a wrong sentence to him!* ? These are all possible in Persian because one can say his feeling at that moment. Isn't such thing in English?

Comment: Your tenses are wrong.  *When I **said** the sentence, I **realized** that I **had said** the sentence incorrectly.*  The realization occurs immediately after the saying.

Comment: If you cast the statement in the present: *I **realize** that I **have given** you the wrong information.*

Comment: If you cast the statement in the past:  *I **realized** that I **had given** him the wrong train schedule.*

Comment: *After I **had handed** him the train schedule, I **realized** that I **had given** him the wrong one.*

Comment: @TRomano Interesting. That reminds me of back shifting discussion in reporting speech. I thought that "He realized that I say something incorrectly" means that "he still thinks that my saying is wrong" I often confuses such sentences.

Comment: @TRomano I know! it seems what I mean is not in English! its something like reporting, however I noticed even in reporting a past sentence you cast the tense to the past.

Comment: @TRomano I know the rules of past and present perfect. but I mean to **report** his feeling just after he said the statement. something like *at that moment I realize I have said something incorrectly*, but it seems its ungrammatical in English, while it is possible in Persian (not sure how grammatical it is in Persian, because 3 versions are possible and understandable) 1. *at that moment I realized I had said something incorrectly*  - 2. *at that moment I realized I have said something incorrectly*  - 3. *at that moment I realize I have said something incorrectly*

Comment: @tromano you may like to see my related comment on the answer of Alen.

Comment: @Cardinal: I would understand *He realized that I **write** with my left hand* to mean "I *always write* with my left hand and he realized that".  But if you're talking about a specific incident in the past: *He realized that I **had written** it with my right hand, and that that was why the penmanship was almost illegible.*

Comment: @Ahmad:  It seems you're trying to use the "historical present". *It **is** then that I **realize**  that I **am using** the term incorrectly.*  That is legitimate when *narrating* a past event.  *It **is** then that I **realize** that I **have given** him the wrong train schedule.*  The tense of the that-clause depends on the time of its action.

Comment: @tromano great! It seems I address that. Good that I  finally found it. I should read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something you did in the past? If so, use the past perfect. The present perfect is a present tense.

You are talking about what you did or said yesterday. You can't say

> *Yesterday I have made a mistake

because *yesterday* excludes the present.

Likewise,  you can't use the present perfect when the time frame of everything that you are talking about was *yesterday*.

Even if the report of the second sentence  comes immediately after the statement of the first sentence, this reporting still happened entirely in the past, thus the present perfect can't be used.

Comment: I know these rules. but I mean to **report** his feeling just after he said the statement. something like *at that moment I realize I have said something incorrectly*. Notice to at that moment.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even if the report comes immediately after the statement of the first sentence, this reporting still happened entirely in the past, thus the present perfect can't be used. Likewise, you cannot say '*At that moment I realize I have said something incorrectly'  because 'at that moment'  is talking about  a past moment, and it excludes the present, so both 'realize' and 'have said' are ungrammatical.

Comment: I see that's not possible in English. Now I have another question. Suppose that I have done a mistake. What it means? It means the effect of that mistake still exists. Right? Now  you ask when did you realize that? I reply yesterday I realized I have done a mistake. Isn't it possible? I can't say yesterday I realized I had done a mistake. Because it'd mean now there is no problem. However it's a new situation and dose'nt relate to my main question.

Comment: '*Yesterday I realized I have made (not: done)  a mistake' is not grammatical. You would usually  say: 'Yesterday I realized I made a mistake'. If you have to put that mistake-making before another past event, you use the past perfect and say 'Yesterday I realized I had made a mistake when I saw my friend laughing at me'.